# How to select and insert value from another DataFrame by id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have two DataFrames:

```
a = [{'id':123, 'name': 'AAA'}, {'id':456, 'name': 'BBB'}, {'id':789, 'name': 'TTT'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df1)

b = [{'id':123}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
print(df2)
```

I need to add the new column in DataFrame `df2['name']`and to add the value from DataFrame `df1['name']` by id. Something like `df2['name'] = [df1['name'] where df2['id'] == df1['id']]`. Yes i can use `pd.merge` but i want to do it try using this logic.

The option like where `df1['id'] = 123` is not considered, because there should be a comparison of id dataframes.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark - Hi, df2['name'] = 'AAA'

Comment: Can you write out the expected output in the form of an edit to your post? It isn't clear to me what you're trying to produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
is using [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df2['name'] = df2['id'].map(df1.set_index('id')['name'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df2

    id name
0  123  AAA
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [{'id':123, 'name': 'AAA'}, {'id':456, 'name': 'BBB'}, {'id':789, 'name': 'TTT'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
b = [{'id':123}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
```